# How to remove previous attributeModifier when new attributeModifier is added?

Tags: java, wicket

I have two columns which are orderbyborder links. When i click one column i changed the color of column by adding attributeModifier in the following way

```
add(new AttributeModifier("style", true, new Model<String>("background-color:#80b6ed;")));
```

This works fine. But when i click on second column, the first column remains the changed color. But I expect only the column which i click should hold this attributeModifier!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shouldn't change the modifier.

The trick is to have your model return the correct value. So instead of using  `new Model<String>("background-color:#80b6ed;")`, which always returns the same constant value, you'd have something like:

```
new Model<String>() {
   @Override
   public String getObject() {
     if( columnName.equals( selectedColumn ) { //or something along these lines, to check if the current column is the selected one
        return "background-color:#80b6ed;";
     }
     return "background-color:white;";
   }
}
```

And of course this also means you can add an attribute modifier to every column when you create them and don't have to worry about them later on.

Comment: Thnx alot...i have this idea to implement..bt your answer gives me the way to achieve....thnx once again...

Answer (score 0):

Another way to achieve what you want is to add a css class to the selected line via Javascript (removing the class from old one).